# Divide columns - oracle

Tags: oracle

[image]

Hello/ I need divide this table

I try use this but have bad result

```
SELECT MIN(y1),
       MAX(y1),
       MIN(redempamount1),
       MAX(redempamount1),
       MIN(f1),
       MIN(f2),
       MAX(f1),
       MAX(f2)
FROM   (SELECT to_number(y1) y1,
               redempamount1,
               add_months('02.03.2018', 12 * y1 - 12) f1,
               add_months('02.03.2018', 12 * y1) - 1 f2,
               row_number() over(PARTITION BY ntl ORDER BY rownum DESC) grp
        FROM   (SELECT to_number(t.y1) y1,
                       redempamount1,
                       add_months('02.03.2018', 12 * y1 - 12) f1,
                       add_months('02.03.2018', 12 * y1) - 1 f2,
                       ntile(2) over(ORDER BY rownum DESC) ntl
                FROM   inspolreport t))
GROUP  BY grp;
```

[image]

```
Y1 REDEMPAMOUNT1 F1         F2
-- ------------- ---------- ----------
 1             0 18.12.2008 17.12.2009
 2       3362.54 18.12.2009 17.12.2010
 3       6030.84 18.12.2010 17.12.2011
 4       8873.52 18.12.2011 17.12.2012
 5       11830.9 18.12.2012 17.12.2013
 6      15041.83 18.12.2013 17.12.2014
 7      18382.37 18.12.2014 17.12.2015
 8      21857.15 18.12.2015 17.12.2016
 9      25472.97 18.12.2016 17.12.2017
10      27359.51 18.12.2017 17.12.2018
11      31690.65 18.12.2018 17.12.2019
12         36195 18.12.2019 17.12.2020
13      40879.06 18.12.2020 17.12.2021
14       45750.5 18.12.2021 17.12.2022
15      53491.44 18.12.2022 17.12.2023
```

expected output

```
Y1 REDEMPAMOUNT1 F1         F2         Y2 REDEMPAMOUNT1 F3         F4
-- ------------- ---------- ---------- -- ------------- ---------- ----------
 1             0 18.12.2008 17.12.2009  9      25472.97 18.12.2016 17.12.2017
 2       3362.54 18.12.2009 17.12.2010 10      27359.51 18.12.2017 17.12.2018
 3       6030.84 18.12.2010 17.12.2011 11      31690.65 18.12.2018 17.12.2019
 4       8873.52 18.12.2011 17.12.2012 12         36195 18.12.2019 17.12.2020
 5       11830.9 18.12.2012 17.12.2013 13      40879.06 18.12.2020 17.12.2021
 6      15041.83 18.12.2013 17.12.2014 14       45750.5 18.12.2021 17.12.2022
 7      18382.37 18.12.2014 17.12.2015 15      53491.44 18.12.2022 17.12.2023
 8      21857.15 18.12.2015 17.12.2016
```

Comment: What is the expected result you want? Also instead of giving image, give your source data in form of text/ascii table and mention your expected output based on that

Comment: Sort all columns,  for example column min(y1) now looks 1 ,6,2,4,5,15,3,7 , I need 1,2,3,4,5,6,7

Comment: Sorry, don't know how add more beautiful

Comment: Denys,Your requirement is not clear please specify in words instead of query what you are expecting,

Comment: I still cant understand what you want. Use dbfiddle.uk / sqlfiddle.com and create sample data and explain the logic for expected output.

Comment: I'm trying to divide the data in columns into two parts in one table and that they would go in order

Comment: Select 1 time, add rownum as pos column; Select 2nd time, add rownum-offset; join select results by pos; filter out every 2nd page. If you don't know how many lines per page, run 3rd time to count.

Comment: I have table http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/136b49/2/0 and need create something like this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/929efb/1/0

Answer (score 0):

If what you want to do is split your results into two side-by-side sets of data, then you will need to pivot your data accordingly.

I can see that is what you're trying to do, but you need to use conditional aggregates to produce the columns.

So you want something like:

```
WITH your_table AS (SELECT 1 y1, 0 redempamount1, to_date('18/12/2008', 'dd/mm/yyyy') f1, to_date('17/12/2009', 'dd/mm/yyyy') f2 FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 2 y1, 3362.54 redempamount1, to_date('18/12/2009', 'dd/mm/yyyy') f1, to_date('17/12/2010', 'dd/mm/yyyy') f2 FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 3 y1, 6030.84 redempamount1, to_date('18/12/2010', 'dd/mm/yyyy') f1, to_date('17/12/2011', 'dd/mm/yyyy') f2 FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 4 y1, 8873.52 redempamount1, to_date('18/12/2011', 'dd/mm/yyyy') f1, to_date('17/12/2011', 'dd/mm/yyyy') f2 FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 5 y1, 15041.83 redempamount1, to_date('18/12/2012', 'dd/mm/yyyy') f1, to_date('17/12/2011', 'dd/mm/yyyy') f2 FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 6 y1, 15041.83 redempamount1, to_date('18/12/2013', 'dd/mm/yyyy') f1, to_date('17/12/2011', 'dd/mm/yyyy') f2 FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 7 y1, 18382.37 redempamount1, to_date('18/12/2014', 'dd/mm/yyyy') f1, to_date('17/12/2011', 'dd/mm/yyyy') f2 FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 8 y1, 21857.15 redempamount1, to_date('18/12/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') f1, to_date('17/12/2011', 'dd/mm/yyyy') f2 FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 9 y1, 25472.97 redempamount1, to_date('18/12/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') f1, to_date('17/12/2011', 'dd/mm/yyyy') f2 FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 10 y1, 27359.51 redempamount1, to_date('18/12/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') f1, to_date('17/12/2011', 'dd/mm/yyyy') f2 FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 11 y1, 31690.65 redempamount1, to_date('18/12/2018', 'dd/mm/yyyy') f1, to_date('17/12/2011', 'dd/mm/yyyy') f2 FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 12 y1, 36195 redempamount1, to_date('18/12/2019', 'dd/mm/yyyy') f1, to_date('17/12/2020', 'dd/mm/yyyy') f2 FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 13 y1, 40879.06 redempamount1, to_date('18/12/2020', 'dd/mm/yyyy') f1, to_date('17/12/2021', 'dd/mm/yyyy') f2 FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 14 y1, 45750.5 redempamount1, to_date('18/12/2021', 'dd/mm/yyyy') f1, to_date('17/12/2022', 'dd/mm/yyyy') f2 FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 15 y1, 53491.44 redempamount1, to_date('18/12/2022', 'dd/mm/yyyy') f1, to_date('17/12/2023', 'dd/mm/yyyy') f2 FROM dual)
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN grp = 1 THEN y1 END) AS y1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN grp = 1 THEN redempamount1 END) AS redempamount1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN grp = 1 THEN f1 END) AS f1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN grp = 1 THEN f2 END) AS f2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN grp = 2 THEN y1 END) AS y2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN grp = 2 THEN redempamount1 END) AS redempamount2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN grp = 2 THEN f1 END) AS f3,
       MAX(CASE WHEN grp = 2 THEN f2 END) AS f4
FROM   (SELECT y1,
               redempamount1,
               f1,
               f2,
               grp,
               row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY grp ORDER BY y1) rn
        FROM   (SELECT y1,
                       redempamount1,
                       f1,
                       f2,
                       NTILE(2) OVER (ORDER BY y1) grp
                FROM   your_table))
GROUP BY rn
ORDER BY rn;

        Y1 REDEMPAMOUNT1 F1          F2                  Y2 REDEMPAMOUNT2 F3          F4
---------- ------------- ----------- ----------- ---------- ------------- ----------- -----------
         1             0 18/12/2008  17/12/2009           9      25472.97 18/12/2016  17/12/2011
         2       3362.54 18/12/2009  17/12/2010          10      27359.51 18/12/2017  17/12/2011
         3       6030.84 18/12/2010  17/12/2011          11      31690.65 18/12/2018  17/12/2011
         4       8873.52 18/12/2011  17/12/2011          12         36195 18/12/2019  17/12/2020
         5      15041.83 18/12/2012  17/12/2011          13      40879.06 18/12/2020  17/12/2021
         6      15041.83 18/12/2013  17/12/2011          14       45750.5 18/12/2021  17/12/2022
         7      18382.37 18/12/2014  17/12/2011          15      53491.44 18/12/2022  17/12/2023
         8      21857.15 18/12/2015  17/12/2011
```

However, if you are in 11g and above, you can use the `PIVOT` command, which I would argue makes your intentions clearer:

```
SELECT o_y1 AS y1,
       o_redempamount1 AS redempamount1,
       o_f1 AS f1,
       o_f2 AS f2,
       t_y1 AS y2,
       t_redempamount1 AS redempamount2,
       t_f1 AS f3,
       t_f2 AS f4
FROM   (SELECT y1,
               redempamount1,
               f1,
               f2,
               grp,
               row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY grp ORDER BY y1) rn
        FROM   (SELECT y1,
                       redempamount1,
                       f1,
                       f2,
                       NTILE(2) OVER (ORDER BY y1) grp
                FROM   your_table))
PIVOT (MAX(y1) AS y1, MAX(redempamount1) AS redempamount1, MAX(f1) AS f1, MAX(f2) AS f2
       FOR grp IN (1 AS o, 2 AS t))
ORDER BY rn;
```

Comment: Unfortunately I use 10g :( I should have said it earlier

Comment: Then the first part of my answer should give you what you need.

Comment: Yes it is works, but what to do when data in table every time updated ?

Comment: You wouldn't need the subquery called "your_table" - you'd just use your table instead. I've only got it there so I can run the main query with some test data, since I don't have your table.

Comment: You just need to ignore the `with your_table as (...)` section; i.e. the main select statement starts with `select max(case when grp = 1 then ...`. If you are unfamiliar with subquery factoring (aka common table expressions aka CTEs), I highly recommend you familiarise yourself with them.